# How to Remove Cardview in android?

Tags: android

I've a problem about remove `CardView` in layout I need to remove perfectly clear 100% not hide something like `setvisibility(View.GONE)` Please save my day Thanks.

[image]

this my code in layout

```
<HorizontalScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="130dp">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/relative1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView_header1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                android:text="Weather"
                android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
                android:textSize="15sp" />

            <!--<android.support.v7.widget.CardView--> this is simple cardview
            <!--android:id="@+id/card_view_1_1"-->
            <!--android:layout_width="270dp"-->
            <!--android:layout_height="wrap_content"-->
            <!--android:layout_below="@+id/textView_header1"-->
            <!--android:layout_gravity="center"-->
            <!--android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"-->
            <!--android:layout_marginRight="15dp"-->
            <!--app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/colorWhite"-->
            <!--app:cardCornerRadius="4dp">-->
        </RelativeLayout>
    </HorizontalScrollView>
```

This is how i create card

```
enter code here
 public void createCard(String hum_val, String temp_val) {
    int humidValTextSize = 35;
    if ((getResources().getConfiguration().screenLayout & Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_MASK) == Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_LARGE) {
        humidValTextSize = 35;
    } else if ((getResources().getConfiguration().screenLayout & Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_MASK) == Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_NORMAL) {
        humidValTextSize = 17;
    }
    /*
    ------Structure of item------

    CardView
        |__RelativeLayout (inside CardView)
                |___ImageView
                |___TextView
                |___TextView
    */

    // Relative Layout inside CardView ---
    RelativeLayout layout_in_card = new RelativeLayout(getActivity());
    layout_in_card.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    layout_in_card.setPadding(15, 15, 15, 15);
    layout_in_card.setMinimumWidth(300);
    // End initialize RelativeLayout_Inside_CardView

    // ImageView inside Relative Layout ---
    ImageView imageView1 = new ImageView(getActivity());

    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutImg = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(80, 80);
    layoutImg.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT);
    layoutImg.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP);
    layoutImg.setMargins(0, 0, 16, 0);

    imageView1.setLayoutParams(layoutImg);
    if (hum_val == null) {
        imageView1.setImageResource(R.drawable.dashboard_nodata);
    } else {
        imageView1.setImageResource(R.drawable.dashboard_humidicon);
    }


    imageView1.setId(Integer.parseInt(currentImageViewId.toString()));
    currentImageViewId++;
    layout_in_card.addView(imageView1);
    // End initialize ImageView ---

    // TextView inside Relative Layout ---
    TextView txtViewName = new TextView(getActivity());

    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutTxtViewName = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
    layoutTxtViewName.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_START);
    layoutTxtViewName.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, imageView1.getId());
    layoutTxtViewName.setMargins(0, 20, 0, 0);

    txtViewName.setText("Humidity");

    //txtViewName.setText("Humidity");
    txtViewName.setTextSize(humidValTextSize);
    txtViewName.setLayoutParams(layoutTxtViewName);

    layout_in_card.addView(txtViewName);
    // End initialize TextView ---

    // TextView inside Relative Layout ---
    TextView txtViewValue = new TextView(getActivity());

    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutTxtViewValue = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
    layoutTxtViewValue.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_BASELINE, imageView1.getId());
    layoutTxtViewValue.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_BOTTOM, imageView1.getId());
    layoutTxtViewValue.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_END);
    layoutTxtViewValue.setMargins(1, 0, 0, 0);
    layoutTxtViewValue.addRule(RelativeLayout.TEXT_ALIGNMENT_GRAVITY, RelativeLayout.CENTER_VERTICAL);

    if (hum_val == null) {
        txtViewValue.setText("N/A");
    } else {
        txtViewValue.setText(hum_val + "%");
    }

    txtViewValue.setTextSize(humidValTextSize);
    txtViewValue.setLayoutParams(layoutTxtViewValue);

    layout_in_card.addView(txtViewValue);
    // End initialize TextView ---


    // CardView Root
    CardView cardView = new CardView(getActivity());
    cardView.setId(Integer.parseInt(currentCardViewId.toString()));
    currentCardViewId++;
    if (currentRefCardViewId == null) {
```

//            currentRefCardViewId = R.id.card_view_1_2;
        }

```
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutCardView = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(270, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
    layoutCardView.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, R.id.textView_header1);
    layoutCardView.addRule(RelativeLayout.TEXT_ALIGNMENT_GRAVITY, RelativeLayout.CENTER_VERTICAL);
    if (currentRefCardViewId != null) {
        layoutCardView.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF, currentRefCardViewId);
    }


    currentRefCardViewId = cardView.getId();
    layoutCardView.setMargins(15, 0, 15, 0);
    cardView.setLayoutParams(layoutCardView);
    cardView.setRadius(4);
    cardView.setCardBackgroundColor(ColorStateList.valueOf(Color.WHITE));
    cardView.setPadding(15, 0, 15, 0);

    cardView.addView(layout_in_card);

    RelativeLayout relativeLayout = (RelativeLayout) getView().findViewById(R.id.relative1);
    relativeLayout.addView(cardView);

    createCard_temp(temp_val);
}
```

Comment: what parent layout you are using..? and what you tried..? share your code.

Comment: if you wish to remove a view, you can use ViewGroup.removeView(View v)

Comment: Hi  Muthukrishnan Rajendran
I'm trying to  remove cardview .
 my parent layout is Relative layout but I add cardview programmatically in JAVA 
I edit my post to share my code thanks

Comment: @Zielony thanks. but I'm newbie So how to get Viewgroup? TT